# What size wire should i use for a 125 foot underground run to a garden shed

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I want to run a buried 125' line to a 30A subpanel in my garden shed. I will only be running hand tools and lighting. Was planning on using 12/3 from the house to the subpanel. Does that sound like the right size wire for the job?

Comment: Are you planning to breaker this feeder at 20A?  How many square feet is the shed?  Is there a reason you want to use a direct bury cable instead of conduit?

Comment: I was going to add 2 - 15 amp breakers in the subpanel - one for the lights and the 2nd for receptacles. The shed is 192 SF. The direct bury cable is going to be used to reduce expense and make it a bit easier to bury. I have really hard clay soil in NC and I think cable will be easier to bury.

Comment: One advantage of conduit is that instead of trenching it, you may be able to use [trenchless techniques](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/77492/27099)...

Comment: And when I say "breaker the feeder at 20A" I'm talking about the breaker at the main-panel end of this line...

Comment: If your intending to use a 30amp breaker in the house the minimum wire size is 10gauge.

Comment: I am planning on a 30 amp breaker in the main panel in the house and then two 15 amp breakers in  the subpanel. Are you suggesting 10/ 3?

Comment: With a 30 amp double pole breaker in the main panel the minimum wire size is 10 or 10/3 in multi-conductor UF cable.  For 125feet with the lighter loads you describe that will also have acceptable voltage drop.  Keep in mind voltage drop increases, as the load increases and/or distance increases.

Comment: Why do you want to use a 30A breaker in the main panel?  Why not a 15 or 20?   I mean it's good to do, to resist voltage drop and for expansion purposes, but not seeing where you need 30 right now.  Will you ever have use for 240V power at the shed?

Comment: The 30 amp breaker was just in case I need extra load ie: for a heater if it gets cold etc...